# try_files doesn't use variables from regex and map

Tags: nginx, configuration

I'm trying to conditionally serve .webp images to supported clients. The images are stored like `image.jpg` and `image.jpg.webp` in the same folder.

I can't get try_files to do what I think it should to. When I use `$1$webp_suffix` as the location it fails and also does not try the second location.

In nginx.conf I set `$webp_suffix` like so:

```
http {
    map $http_accept $webp_suffix {
        default "";
        "~*webp"    ".webp";
    }
    include /opt/local/etc/nginx/vhosts/*;
}
```

But when I try to use the suffix in my virtual host I get an error 404.

```
server {
  
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my.example.com;

    # allow /data/ and /data/343/ as public URL
    location ~ ^/data/[0-9/]*(.*)$ {
        expires 365d;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
        # Serve webp images when available and supported
        location ~ ^/data/[0-9/]*(.+\.(png|jpg))$ {
            add_header Vary Accept;
            alias /local/path/httpdocs/data/;
            try_files $1$webp_suffix $1 =404;
        }
        alias /Users/r/Sites/cms/httpdocs/data;
        try_files /$1 =404;
    }
}
```

Everything works when I remove `$1$webp_suffix`, so the paths and such seem correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `$1`. It gets overwritten each time Nginx evaluates a regular expression. The expression `$1$webp_suffix` causes Nginx to evaluate the regular expression in the `map` statement, which simultaneously causes `$1` to become an empty string.

Use a named capture in the `location` statements.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/data/[0-9/]*(?<filename>.*)$ {
    expires 365d;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
    # Serve webp images when available and supported
    location ~ \.(png|jpg)$ {
        add_header Vary Accept;
        root /local/path/httpdocs/data/;
        try_files /$filename$webp_suffix /$filename =404;
    }
    root /Users/r/Sites/cms/httpdocs/data;
    try_files /$filename =404;
}
```

Also, you should be using `root` instead of `alias`.